# PHP/HTML Button works only in the first element from a loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am learning PHP and am stuck right now. In a while loop, all the to-do items are displayed. Each of these elements has a delete button and a check button. The delete button works in every element, but the check button only works in the first one. The check button is to be used to check off an element. When the check button is pressed, an error message is displayed that this element could not be deleted. Only in the first element of course not. I can't find the error.

I suspect there is something wrong with the  in the index

```
        <?php
        $todos = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM todos ORDER BY id DESC");
    ?>
    <div class="show-todo-section">
        <?php if($todos->rowCount() <= 0){ ?>
            <div class="todo-item">
                <div class="empty">
                    <img src="img/f.png" width="100%" />
                    <img src="img/Ellipsis.gif" width="80px">
                </div>
                
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php while($todo = $todos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
            <div class="todo-item">
 
                <form action="app/checked.php" method="POST">
                    <button class="check-box" value="<?php echo $todo['id']; ?>" name='checked' type="submit">Check</button>
                </form>

                <form action="app/delete.php" method="POST">                 
                    <button class="remove-to-do" value="<?php echo $todo['id']; ?>" name='delete' type="submit">x</button>
                </from> 

                <?php if($todo['checked']){ ?>                      
                    <h2 class="checked"><?php echo $todo['title'] ?></h2>
                <?php }else { ?>  
                    <h2><?php echo $todo['title'] ?></h2>
                <?php } ?>
                
                <small>created: <?php echo $todo['date_time'] ?></small> 
                <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $todo['coins']; $i++) {
                    echo "<img class='coins' src='img/coin.gif' width='40px' />";
                } ?>            
                
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

the checked.php

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['checked'])) {
   require '../db_conn.php';

   $id = $_POST['checked'];

   if(empty($id)){
       header("Location: ../index.php?mess=errorChecked". $id);
   }else{
        
    $todos = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, checked FROM todos WHERE id=?");
    $todos->execute([$id]);

    $todo = $todos->fetch();
    $uId = $todo['id'];
    $checked = $todo['checked'];

    $uChecked = $checked ? 0 : 1;

    $res = $conn->query("UPDATE todos SET checked=$uChecked WHERE id=$uId");

    header("Location: ../index.php?mess=successChecked");
    $conn = null;
    exit();
   }

} else{  
   header("Location: ../index.php?mess=errorChecked");

}
```

Comment: What database are you using? I think you have an error in prepare statement. $todos->execute([$id]) seems wrong. Don't have you to use bind statement?

Comment: It's possible the form tag on the delete form is messing up the rest of the form. You have an invalid close tag, `</from>` => should be => `</form>`

Comment: @Rasclatt thanks, I didn't see that at all. Now it works!